# cannot start docker when using chroot

Tags: linux, docker, opensuse, systemd, sockets

I am trying to build a custom distribution that runs docker. I am using  [kiwi framework](https://opensource.suse.com/kiwi/overview.html) to achieve that. Docker installation is done successfully during the build. The problem is that I want to load some docker images during the build process so that the system includes all needed images when it starts. The problem is that the KIWI software uses `chroot` to run commands like docker load, docker pull. These commands need a running docker daemon. When I try to start the deamon, it always fails. I tried the following things:

running docker through : `systemctl start docker` failed (systemctl by design will refuse starting a service in chroot jail)

running docker through: `/usr/bin/dockerd` also fails and generates the below logs

```
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25.861184013+01:00" level=warning msg="Error while setting daemon root propagation, this is not generally critical but may cause some functionality to not work or fallback to less desirable behavior" dir=/var/lib/docker error="error getting daemon root's parent mount: Can't find mount point of /var/lib/docker"
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25.861693151+01:00" level=info msg="libcontainerd: started new docker-containerd process" pid=19256
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25.861719642+01:00" level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"unix\"" module=grpc
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25.861728310+01:00" level=info msg="scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25.861756358+01:00" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd.sock 0  <nil>}]" module=grpc
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25.861765096+01:00" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25.861797149+01:00" level=info msg="pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc4203c57b0, CONNECTING" module=grpc
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25+01:00" level=info msg="starting containerd" revision=468a545b9edcd5932818eb9de8e72413e616e86e version=v1.1.2 
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.content.v1.content"..." type=io.containerd.content.v1 
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1 
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25+01:00" level=warning msg="failed to load plugin io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs" error="failed to find the mount info for "/var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs"" 
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.aufs"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1 
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25+01:00" level=warning msg="failed to load plugin io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.aufs" error="modprobe aufs failed: "modprobe: FATAL: Module aufs not found in directory /lib/modules/4.12.14-lp150.12.45-default\n": exit status 1" 
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.native"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1 
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1 
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1 
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25+01:00" level=warning msg="failed to load plugin io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs" error="failed to find the mount info for "/var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs"" 
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.metadata.v1.bolt"..." type=io.containerd.metadata.v1 
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25+01:00" level=warning msg="could not use snapshotter btrfs in metadata plugin" error="failed to find the mount info for "/var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs"" 
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25+01:00" level=warning msg="could not use snapshotter aufs in metadata plugin" error="modprobe aufs failed: "modprobe: FATAL: Module aufs not found in directory /lib/modules/4.12.14-lp150.12.45-default\n": exit status 1" 
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25+01:00" level=warning msg="could not use snapshotter zfs in metadata plugin" error="failed to find the mount info for "/var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs"" 
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.differ.v1.walking"..." type=io.containerd.differ.v1 
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.gc.v1.scheduler"..." type=io.containerd.gc.v1 
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.containers-service"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1 
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.content-service"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1 
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.diff-service"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1 
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.images-service"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1 
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.leases-service"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1 
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.namespaces-service"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1 
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.snapshots-service"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1 
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.monitor.v1.cgroups"..." type=io.containerd.monitor.v1 
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux"..." type=io.containerd.runtime.v1 
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.tasks-service"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1 
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.containers"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1 
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.content"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1 
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.diff"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1 
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.events"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1 
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.healthcheck"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1 
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.images"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1 
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.leases"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1 
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.namespaces"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1 
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.snapshots"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1 
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.tasks"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1 
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.version"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1 
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.introspection"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1 
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25+01:00" level=info msg=serving... address="/var/run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd-debug.sock" 
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25+01:00" level=info msg=serving... address="/var/run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd.sock" 
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25+01:00" level=info msg="containerd successfully booted in 0.008216s" 
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25.884102534+01:00" level=info msg="pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc4203c57b0, READY" module=grpc
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25.887492664+01:00" level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"unix\"" module=grpc
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25.887505949+01:00" level=info msg="scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25.887530644+01:00" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd.sock 0  <nil>}]" module=grpc
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25.887540195+01:00" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25.887563400+01:00" level=info msg="pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc4201821f0, CONNECTING" module=grpc
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25.887660990+01:00" level=info msg="pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc4201821f0, READY" module=grpc
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25.909326944+01:00" level=info msg="Graph migration to content-addressability took 0.00 seconds"
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25.909459182+01:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup memory limit"
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25.909468854+01:00" level=warning msg="Unable to find cpu cgroup in mounts"
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25.909473921+01:00" level=warning msg="Unable to find blkio cgroup in mounts"
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25.909478263+01:00" level=warning msg="Unable to find cpuset cgroup in mounts"
time="2019-02-04T16:00:25.909552255+01:00" level=warning msg="mountpoint for pids not found"
Error starting daemon: Devices cgroup isn't mounted
```

**Is there any technique to start docker daemon in a chroot Jail ?**

Comment: @Biswapriyo no problem I will try to adapt your solution to my case.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

the chroot needs cgroups
- you have to ensure the chroot has the correct file systems mounted `/proc` `/dev` `/sys`, which you can either mount again or rbind from host
- then you need to mount the cgroups inside the jail (if you have rbinded `/sys` you might already have them in `/sys/fs/cgroup`). You can use [these scripts](https://github.com/tianon/cgroupfs-mount) to mount cgroups.
- then you start docker

Since you can't load kernel modules from a chroot you have to ensure those are mounted beforehand, like `overlay` for the storage driver and `nf_conntrack` for networking. 
Alternatively you can always fallback to the `vfs` storage driver and disabling iptables...

Comment: Starting dockerd in my chroot after mounting proc, dev, and sys, fails with `failed to start daemon: Devices cgroup isn't mounted`. I see that `/sys/fs/cgroup` is available (but empty) from with my chroot because I mounted sys. Can you be more specific re the commands to mount the cgroups beyond mounting sys?